# using date time with operators

Tags: database, sqlite

The task i'm trying to solve is this:
Within a square cell with sides of length 1450m that is centered on the bike station at British Museum, Bloomsbury over a 4 hour period commencing at 6am.

I have two tables,
the station tables and usage tables. However, after running my query, all rows are empty!

```
SELECT ce.stationID,
       il.name,
       il.easting,
       il.northing,
       il.capacity,
       ce.t,
       ROUND(AVG(availableBikes) ,1) as Average,
       ROUND(AVG(availableBikes)/capacity*100,1) AS Percentage
FROM tflBikeUsagehour ce,
     tflStations il
where il.usageId=ce.stationID
  and datetime (t,'06:00:00')>6
  AND datetime (t,' 10:00:00')<10
  AND il.easting BETWEEN (SELECT easting-(1450*0.5) FROM tflstations
                          WHERE name='British Museum, Bloomsbury')
                     AND (SELECT easting+(1450*0.5) FROM tflstations
                          WHERE name='British Museum, Bloomsbury')
  AND il.northing BETWEEN (SELECT northing-(1450*0.5) FROM tflstations
                           WHERE name='British Museum, Bloomsbury')
                      AND (SELECT northing+(1450*0.5) FROM tflstations
                           WHERE name='British Museum, Bloomsbury')
  and ce.t between (select datetime(t,'06:00:00')<6 as tf from tflbikeusagehour)
               and (select datetime(t,'10:00:00')>10 from tflbikeusagehour)
GROUP BY ce.t
ORDER BY ce.t;
```

My problem is with the date time format! Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [datetime function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) cannot be used this way.

To check whether a timestamp is in a range, use an expression like this:

```
time(t) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '09:59:59'
```

If the column `t` already uses the format `hh:mm:ss`, you can replace `time(t)` with `t`.